# What are some examples of fixed point problems where transfinite constructions elucidated the problem?

Tags: logic, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, transfinite-induction

Maths is filled with various different kind of "fixed point theorems", sometimes even when they are not phrased as such, where we have an operation $f$ on objects of a certain kind and wish to find an object $X$ such that $X = f(X)$. Methods of proof vary but many can be essentially proved by something along the lines:

*"Start with any object $X$, apply $f$ repeatedly and as you go agglomerate the images of $X$ together in some way. Then if you do this enough times and maybe take a limit and you'll reach a fixed point."*

Some examples of what I'm talking about are:

- Let $\omega$ be some $n$th root of unity. Is there a number $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\omega\cdot z = z$? Well we could just start with 1 and then $\omega\cdot 1 = \omega$. Then we "agglomerate" to get $1+\omega$ which might not work so we multiply by $\omega$ to $\omega + \omega^2$... Doing this enough times gives us the expression $1+\omega + \ldots + \omega^{n-1}$ which is invariant under multiplication by $\omega$, since $\omega \cdot (1+ \omega + \ldots + \omega^{n-1}) = \omega + \omega^2 + \ldots + \omega^{n-1} + 1$. Indeed, this number is zero (as could actually be seen by thinking about the equation directly but this is illustrative of the method).
- Suppose we want a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that its derivative is equal to itself, i.e. $f' = f$. Here we could start with any polynomial and then eventually get $0$, which works. Alternatively, looking for a more interesting situation, we could actually work backwards and ask for a function whose derivative is zero. Say we pick $1$, perhaps out of simplicity, and then again move backwards to get $x$ and then again to get $\frac{x^2}{2}$ etc. and agglomerating all these we get $1, 1+x, 1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2},\ldots$ which some sense of a limit becomes $e^x = 1+x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots$
- Suppose we want to find an even function, i.e. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$. Start with any function $f_0$ at all, perform the "evenness map" to it to form $f_1$ defined as $f_1(x) := f_0(-x)$ and then agglomerate it with the original function to form $f_1 + f_0$, which is even. Slight variants on this reasoning are how you prove any real function is the sum of an even and an odd function, how you prove that every square matrix is the sum of a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix and how you prove that every function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation is the difference of two monotone functions.

I could go on to give more examples (every normal function on the ordinals has a fixed point, etc.) of this proof technique but hopefully it's clear. What I wish to ask about is when this kind of process was made to work by using *transfinite iteration*.

I know of essentially only one application of this: the [automorphism tower problem for groups](http://jdh.hamkins.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/AutoTowers-Bristol-2012.pdf). The problem of trying to understand the long-term behaviour of the sequence $G, \text{Aut}(G), \text{Aut(Aut(}G)),\ldots$ for a given group $G$ was posed some time ago and people were interested in knowing if every such sequence eventually became constant regardless of the starting $G$. Various pieces of work were done until [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins) came and proved that it was most natural to extend the automorphism sequences transfinitely, at which point it was clear that yes every such sequence terminates.

---

Sorry for the long build up but the question ultimately is:

**Are there other examples of such transfinite iteration being used to find a fixed point or more generally construct some important object?**

Comment: Not really used to show the existence of a fixed point but you do have the Cantor Bendixson rank of a set of reals is defined as the ordinal number of "times" you need to apply the derived set to get to a fixed point.

Comment: @Math_Images_Only: this is relevant! As I was trying to explain in the preamble, I care more generally about invariant objects under various kinds of operators. Could you write up a little more about this example and maybe an outline of how the sequence was guaranteed to become eventually constant?

Comment: Fixed points of normal functions from transfinite ordinals to transfinite ordinals ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions), [Examples](https://mathoverflow.net/a/420235/15780)) and the several fairly general examples one can find in my 3-part answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) (e.g. "Fixed Points of Monotone Closure Operators" and "Topological Modification of a Čech Closure Operator").

Answer (score 1):

There is the Sadovskij construction for a map $f\colon K\to X$ with $K$ being a subset of a topological vector space $X$.

$K_0:=K$, $K_{\omega+1}:=\overline{\mathop{conv}} f(K_{\omega}\cap K)$, and $K_\lambda:=\bigcap_{0<\omega<\lambda}K_\omega$ if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal.

Then $K_\lambda$ is eventually constant $K_\infty$, and in particular $f(K_\infty\cap K)\subseteq K_\infty$; if $K_\infty$ is nonempty and compact and contained in $K$ and $X$ is a locally convex space and $f$ is continuous on $K_\infty$ then $f$ has a fixed point by Schauder's fixed point theorem. (The non-emptyness can be ensured by a slight modification of the construction, and the compactness holds if $f$ is a so-called “condensing” map, that is, if for every set $M$ the image $f(M)$ is “more compact” than $M$). Similar constructions work also for multivalued maps and in the more general context of degree theory (when $K_\infty$ is in general not a subset of $K$).

However, the transfinite induction can usually be avoided by considering the intersection $M_\infty$ of all closed convex sets $M$ satisfying $f(M\cap K)\subseteq M$ (in general, $M_\infty\subseteq K_\infty$). Moreover, under very mild assumptions, it can already be proved that $K_\lambda$ is already compact for the first infinite ordinal $\lambda=\omega_0$.

The original paper about the so-called ultimate range $K_\infty$ is

B.N. Sadovskii, *Limit-Compact and Condensing Operators* (in Russian), Uspekhi Mat. Nauk **27** 1972 (1), 81-146.

The English translation appeared in Russian Math. Surveys **27** 1972 (1), 85-155.

The sets $M_\infty$ are usually called fundamental sets and were introduced by M.A. Krasnoselskii, P.P. Zabrejko, or V.V. Obukhovskii - I really do not know which is the first reference here.

The fact that $K_{\omega_0}$ is at the first infinite ordinal cocompact for a much larger class of maps than one might expect at a first glance is highly nontrivial and was perhaps first observed by myself in M. Väth, *Fixed point theorem and fixed point index for countably condensing maps*, Topol. Methods Nonlinear Anal. **13** 1999 (2), 341-363.

Meanwhile, fundamental sets are a standard approach to define a degree theory for non-compact maps. As mentioned, the approach works for large classes of multi-valued maps as well as for coincidence points, and actually even combinations of both.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give more detail about the construction? In particular, could you outline why the sequence is eventually constant?

Comment: It is a decreasing (with respect to set inclusion) sequence, and if $K_{\omega+1}=K_\omega$ for some $\omega$, then the sequence is constant from that $\omega$. Now it is just a cardinality argument which shows that the sequence cannot be strictly decreasing for all ordinal indices. (Here the axiom of choice is used to associate a cardinality to $K$.)

Comment: One modification of the construction which makes sure that $K_\infty$ is nonempty is to fix a point $x_0\in K$ and to put $K_{\omega+1}=\overline{\mathop{conv}}(f(K_\omega\cap K)\cup\{x_0\})$.

Similarly, for the definition of $M_\infty$ consider only sets $M$ with the additional property $x_0\in M$.

Comment: My memory was wrong: $K_{\omega_0}$ is only compact under rather weak assumptions (the sequence is not necessarily constant from $\omega_0$ on, but once one has compactness this is not needed for any practical purposes). I edited the text correspondingly.

Comment: Maybe to shed a proper light on the result: If $\gamma$ is a measure of noncompactness and $\gamma(f(M))\le q\gamma(M)$ for every set $M$ with some constant $q<1$, then it is easy to see that $K_{\omega_0}$ is compact. With the Sadovskii construction it suffices to have $\gamma(f(M))<\gamma(M)$ for every not relatively compact $M$ to get a compact $K_\infty$. Surprisingly, in this case already $K_{\omega_0}$ is compact (that is, the Sadvoskii construction is not really needed in this case, but this was not known when Sadovskii made the construction).